# Error handling for Match inside a class - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, match

I have a VBA class that I call to fetch column numbers for the required columns in a worksheet (15 of them). Users are allowed to move columns around and the match functionality works well. However if   a user deletes a column, I get a runtime error. How do I trap an error and let the user know that 'X' column name has been deleted but still continue checking the rest of the columns.

```
Option Explicit
Public EmpName As Long, EmpID As Long, EmpDepartment As Long, EmpAddress As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range, tStr As String, wsname As String
Set ws = ActiveSheet:   Set r = ws.Range("1:1")

EmpName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("EmpName", r.value, 0)
EmpID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("EmpID", r.value, 0)
EmpDepartment = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("EmpDepartment", r.value, 0)
EmpAddress = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("EmpAddress", r.value, 0)

Set r = Nothing: Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Original code updated

To avoid the run-time error you could use `Application.Match` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public EmpName As Long, EmpID As Long, EmpDepartment As Long, EmpAddress As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range, tStr As String, wsname As String
Dim Res As Variant

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set r = ws.Range("1:1")
    
    Res = Application.Match("EmpName", r.Value, 0)
    If Not IsError(Res) Then
        EmpName = Res
    Else
        MsgBox "EmpName column not found!", vbInformation, "Missing Column"
    End If
    
    Res = Application.Match("EmpID", r.Value, 0)
    If Not IsError(Res) Then
        EmpID = Res
    Else
        MsgBox "EmpID column not found!", vbInformation, "Missing Column"
    End If
    
    Res = Application.Match("EmpDepartment", r.Value, 0)
    If Not IsError(Res) Then
        EmpName = Res
    Else
        MsgBox "EmpDepartment column not found!", vbInformation, "Missing Column"
    End If
    
    Res = Application.Match("EmpAddress", r.Value, 0)
    If Not IsError(Res) Then
        EmpAddress = Res
    Else
        MsgBox "EmpAddress column not found!", vbInformation, "Missing Column"
    End If

End Sub
```

### Using a dictionary

If you don't want all the repetition in the code you might want to look at using a dictionary to store the column names/numbers.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range, tStr As String, wsname As String
Dim dicCols As Object
Dim arrCols As Variant
Dim Res As Variant
Dim idx As Long

    arrCols = Array("EmpName", "EmpID", "EmpDepartmen", "EmpAddress")

    Set dicCols = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set r = ws.Range("1:1")

    For idx = LBound(arrCols) To UBound(arrCols)
        Res = Application.Match(arrCols(idx), r.Value, 0)
        If Not IsError(Res) Then
            dicCols(arrCols(idx)) = Res
        Else
            dicCols(arrCols(idx)) = "Not Found"
            MsgBox arrCols(idx) & " column not found!", vbInformation, "Missing Column"
        End If
    Next idx

End Sub
```

Once this code is executed you can use `dicCols(ColumnName)` to get the column number.

For example, wherever you refer to the variable `EmpName` in the rest of the  code you can use `dicCols("EmpName")`.

### Using a dictionary populated from a function

Another refinement might be to use a function to create the dictionary.

This would allow you to pass different sets of column names when required.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public dicCols As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range, tStr As String, wsname As String
Dim arrColNames As Variant
Dim arrNotFound() As Variant
Dim ky As Variant
Dim cnt As Long

    arrColNames = Array("EmpName", "EmpID", "EmpDepartment", "EmpAddress")

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set r = ws.Range("1:1")

    Set dicCols = GetColNos(arrColNames, r)

    For Each ky In dicCols.keys
        If dicCols(ky) = "Not Found" Then
            cnt = cnt + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrNotFound(1 To cnt)
            arrNotFound(cnt) = ky
        End If
    Next ky
    
    If cnt > 0 Then
        MsgBox "The following columns were not found:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Join(arrNotFound, vbCrLf), vbInformation, "Missing Columna"
    End If
    
End Sub

Function GetColNos(arrColNames, rngHdr As Range) As Object
Dim dic As Object
Dim idx As Long
Dim Res As Variant

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For idx = LBound(arrColNames) To UBound(arrColNames)
        Res = Application.Match(arrColNames(idx), rngHdr.Value, 0)
        If Not IsError(Res) Then
            dic(arrColNames(idx)) = Res
        Else
            dic(arrColNames(idx)) = "Not Found"
        End If
    Next idx

    Set GetColNos = dic
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Norie . Is there a way to pass the error handling to a function so that I don't have to repeat the "if Not IsError" and msgbox lines?